# Add pattern inside $in, and aggregate

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I am adding a pattern inside an `$in` in an `aggregate` function.

I know there values exist but my query is returning nothing for the pattern.

Here is my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$tags"},
{'$match': 
{
'tags.tag.name': {
    "$in": ['AA', 'CS', '/Nie/i']},
'auditRun': 12345}},
{'$project': {
 'tags.tag.name':1,
  '_id': 0}},])
```

I am getting results for **AA** and **CS** but I am not getting anything back for the **Nie**.

I am expecting a few results for that as well because I have a bunch of names starting with **Nie**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try without quotes like `{"$in": ['AA', 'CS', /Nie/i]}`

Comment: @Veeram I get a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `$or` operator along with `$regex` to separately lookup the items you need a regular expression search on. It cannot be combined into a single list of items.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$tags"
},
{
    '$match': {
        $or: [
          {'tags.tag.name': {"$in": ['AA','CS']}},
          {'tags.tag.name': { $regex: 'Nie', $options: 'i'}}
        ],
      'auditRun': 12345
    }
},
{
    '$project': {
        'tags.tag.name': 1,
        '_id': 0
    }
},
])
```

Also want to mention that if you only need the ones that *start with* Nie, then your regex should be `^Nie`